# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/neo4j/cypherdsl/grammar/Execute

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have a project using spring mvc, and neo4j. After upgrading the dependencies, I am now getting the error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/neo4j/cypherdsl/grammar/Execute". I want to see if I'm using incompatible packages together.

I changed packages to the following:
neo4j-kernel: 1.8.2
neo4j-cypher: 1.8.2
neo4j-cypher-dsl: 1.7
spring-data-neo4j: 2.1.0.RELEASE
spring-data-neo4j-rest: 2.1.0.RELEASE

When browsing the neo4j-cypher-dsl-1.7, I don't see a grammer subpackage. I'm wondering if this is the problem, or perhaps I'm missing something.

Hopefully that is enough info, if not, please let me know what to include.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're  mixing 1.7 and 1.8 versions. Use the following instead:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-cypher-dsl</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

In 1.7, the Execute class resides in "org.neo4j.cypherdsl" package.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this out when I get a chance, which will have to be later today.